# Prevent EF Code First from inheriting indexes in TPT

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We have a code first model that looks like this.

[image: Code First Model]

`SuitabilityCheck` is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class SuitabilityCheck : ISharded
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index("IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int Id
    { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public Guid ShardKey
    { get; set; }
}
```

When we generate the migration the part of the index that is defined on the `Id` column gets propagated through the hierarchy so each level of the hierarchy gets one or more additional indexes.

`BackgroundSuitabilityCheck` gets the following additional index created because when the `Id` column propagates down so does the part of the index declared on it.

```
.Index(t => t.Id, unique: true, name: "IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id")
```

`RecurringBackgroundSuitabilityCheck` gets two additional indexes created, one from its immediate parent (i.e. `BackgroundSuitabilityCheck`) and one from its parent's parent (i.e. `SuitabilityCheck`).

```
.Index(t => t.Id, unique: true, name: "IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id")
.Index(t => t.Id, name: "IX_BackgroundSuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id")
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to prevent EF from propagating this index down through the hierarchy?

I know we could use something like the Seed method of the migration configuration to remove the indexes we don't want, but then the database doesn't match the model that EF thinks is present which may cause an impedance mismatch down the road. I'd rather tell EF not to cascade the index down the hierarchy.

Comment: Can you show/describe the table-layout you want to get for these classes? By default, EF will have a different table/class. It's possible to make it do otherwise, but it really depends on your target DB Schema.

Comment: Change the `Up` and `Down` method in your migration code? With table per class, `Id` of `RecurringBackgroundSuitabilityCheck` is in a different table and thus the separate index is justified

Comment: @Eris: We're getting the table layout we want. It basically mirrors the class layout, with a `SuitabilityCheck` table that has subtypes of `BackgroundSuitabilityCheck` and `DrugTestSuitabilityCheck`. `RecurringBackgroundSuitabilityCheck` is a subtype of `BackgroundSuitabilityCheck` because it is one with the addition of a date when the check should occur.

Comment: @grek: Changing the `Up` and `Down` methods would be an option, except we're pre-production so at the moment we're regenerating the `Initial` migration whenever a change occurs so devs would have to remember to make that change each time they regen `Initial`. I disagree that the initial index is justified though, as `Recurring` has a 1:1 with `Background` so there is already a PK on the `Id` column of `Recurring`.

Comment: @CraigW. I'm kinda curious, whether my answer helped you solving the problem ;)

Comment: @grek40: Haven't had time to digest the response yet, a couple of other higher priority items came up. Might be a few days before I get back to it.

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of my answer is, to prevent automatic index creation for foreign keys on primary key columns. Another one is related to the composition of your index in the question example.

### Avoid ForeignKey Index Creation

Unfortunately, I know no way of telling EF, **not** to automatically create an index on one specific property. It is possible to remove the index creation statement in the `Up` and `Down` method of the migration code. A different approach would be, to generally disable the automatic creation of indices on foreign keys, which is possible with `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ForeignKeyIndexConvention`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
}
```

This solves the problem in case that no explicit index annotation exists. The trade-off would be, that any foreign key index that is actually desired needs to be added explicitely now (which is at least possible, unlike removing a planned index).

**Follow-Up**

After some more experimenting I realized, that `ForeignKeyIndexConvention` is a great base to start with for more granular rules: Derive a custom convention, override the `Apply` function and selectively call the `base.Apply` function for cases, where automatic ForeignKey index creation is desired. As a rule of thumb, index on FK should be reasonable for any-to-many relations, while one-to-one or zero/one-to-one relations would typically involve a PK/FK combination where no additional index is needed:

```
public class ForeignKeyNotPkIndexConvention : ForeignKeyIndexConvention
{
    public override void Apply(AssociationType item, DbModel model)
    {
        if (item.AssociationEndMembers.Any(x => x.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many))
            base.Apply(item, model);
    }
}
```

Adding this convention instead of the original `ForeignKeyIndexConvention` should deal with most (all?) cases, where the FK is not a PK.

### Avoid Explicitely configured Index in subclasses

However, even without `ForeignKeyIndexConvention`, explicitely annotated indices are propagated through the hierarchy. This can be solved by not explicitely annotating an index on the Id column. In your case this would mean, only having a non-unique index on the `ShardKey` property. This makes sense, since `Id` as PK is indexed anyway, so in terms of accessability it is not needed as second element of the composite index and in terms of uniqueness it is unique even without the `ShardKey`, so having the compound uniqueness is redundant.

**Alternative**

If you have good reason to keep the ID column as part of the composite index, you have the option to re-map the whole table via fluent api. This way, the index stays local to the mapped table instead of spreading in the inheritance hierarchy

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<SuitabilityCheck>().HasKey(x => x.Id)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.Property(y => y.ShardKey).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
            x.Property(y => y.Id).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_SuitabilityCheck_ShardKey_Id", 2)));
            // Mention all other columns of SuitabilityCheck, otherwise the class is split into multiple tables
        });
}
```

As commented, the `Map` command would normally allow you to split your table mapping, so thats what actually happens if you forget any property in the re-mapping.